# Conditional Probability for Noisy Channel

Tags: probability

For a noisy binary channel where $Y = X + N$, $X = \{-v,v\}$, the pdf of N, and priors of X are known, I'm confused when trying to show why $P[Y \le x | X = -v] \rightarrow P[N \le x + v]$.

Intuitively I can say the relationship makes sense but I feel that I should be able to write it explicitly as a result of applying the definition of conditional probability. 
$$P[Y \le x| X = -v]$$
$$P[X + N \le x| X = -v]$$
$$\frac{P[\{X + N \le x\} \cap \{X = -v\}]}{P[X = -v]}$$

After this, I'm inclined to rewrite $P[\{X + N \le x\} \cap \{X = -v\}]$ as $P[N \le x + v]$ but this leaves the prior in the denominator. What am I doing wrong here? Am I misinterpreting $P[Y \le x | X = -v]$ somehow where instead of using the definition of conditional probability I should immediately substitute $X$ for $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After this, I'm inclined to rewrite $\mathsf P[\{X+N≤x\}\cap\{X=−v\}]$ as $\mathsf P[N≤x+v]$ but this leaves the prior in the denominator. What am I doing wrong here?

No, you are good up to there, but: $$\mathsf P[\{X{+}N{\leq}x\}\cap\{X{=}{-}v\}] \;=\; \mathsf P[\{N{\leq}x{+}v\}\cap\{X{=}{-}v\}]$$

Now, are $N, X$ independent?

Comment: Ah, their being independent was in the back of my mind as a way to cancel the prior but I did not make the connection to the given realization of $X$. $N$ is independent of $X$, given the value of $X$ and we can see this via substitution of the realized value. Thank you!